What is the solution for OpenCV installation error?
When I try to install OpenCV via pip using command pip install opencv-python. I receive this error:
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.10.0.84.tar.gz (95.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Collecting cmake>=3.1
        Using cached cmake-3.30.0.tar.gz (31 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
        exit code: 2

        [70 lines of output]
        Collecting ninja>=1.5
          Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1-cp311-cp311-mingw_x86_64.whl
        Collecting cmake
          Using cached cmake-3.30.0.tar.gz (31 kB)
        ERROR: Exception:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in exc_logging_wrapper
            status = run_func(*args)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
            return func(self, options, args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
            requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
            result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
            state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
            self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
            if not criterion.candidates:
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
            return bool(self._sequence)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 174, in __bool__
            return any(self)
                   ^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 162, in <genexpr>
            return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 53, in _iter_built
            candidate = func()
                        ^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 185, in _make_candidate_from_link
            base: Optional[BaseCandidate] = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 231, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
            self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 303, in __init__
            super().__init__(
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 158, in __init__
            self.dist = self._prepare()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 235, in _prepare
            dist = self._prepare_distribution()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 314, in _prepare_distribution
            return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 527, in prepare_linked_requirement
            return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 642, in _prepare_linked_requirement
            dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
            with build_tracker.track(req, tracker_id):
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
            return next(self.gen)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\build\build_tracker.py", line 136, in track
            self.add(req, tracker_id)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\build\build_tracker.py", line 102, in add
            raise LookupError(message)
        LookupError: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/6e/969bd8e01358730ddcfce4a04a7caa8ab3c5e2fd1f1bbad9e6b6276c8b54/cmake-3.30.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org/simple/cmake/) (requires-python:>=3.7) is already being built: cmake>=3.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/6e/969bd8e01358730ddcfce4a04a7caa8ab3c5e2fd1f1bbad9e6b6276c8b54/cmake-3.30.0.tar.gz
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
      exit code: 2

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I have Windows 11
I upgraded pip at version : pip 24.1.2
I upgraded setuptools and wheel.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages (24.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages (70.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages (0.43.0)

I use python version:
Python 3.11.5

I would not try to compile openCV using pip, which you ahve to do since you are using mingw. I would download the opencv source code and compile it yourself using cmake + mingw-make. I have not done this myself, so I cannot give an answer, but I don't think compiling this large&complex library using pip is probably not a good idea

please describe your environment. [mre]. if pip tries to build opencv, that's an issue with your environment. especially on Windows, that should never happen.

Honestly. if you're a beginner, than using MSYS on Windows seems like unnecessary masochism. Just use regular Windows build of Python, along with the standard pre-built OpenCV binaries. It's really amazing the number of people who willingly run head first into a wall for no good reason.

Your problem will be solved. I got an answer from @acw1668. Actually, I couldn't find his answer or my answer.
